# SolrCloud: round-robin replicas not working when using Collections API

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, solrcloud

I've followed the "[Getting Started Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Getting+Started+with+SolrCloud)", the Two-Shards / Two-Replicas secnario and everything worked perfectly.
Then I started using the Collections API which is the preferable way of managing collection,shards and replication.

I launched two instances locally (afterwards with AWS, same problem)
I created a new collection with two shards using the following command:
/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=collection1&numShards=2&collection.configName=collection
This successfully created two shards, one on each instance.
Then I launched another instance, expecting it to automatically set itself as a replica for the first shard, just like in the example. That didn't happen.

Is there something I'm missing?

There were two ways I was able to achieve this:

1. Manually, using the Collections API, I added a replica to shard1 and then another to shard2.
   This is not good enough, as I will need to have this done automatically with Auto Scaling, so I'll need to micro-manage each server "role" - which replicas of which shards of which collections its handling, which complicates things a lot
2. The second way, which I couldn't find a documentation for is to launch an instance with a folder named "collectionX", inside a file named core.properties. In it the following line:
   collection=collection1
   Each instance I launched that way was automatically added as a replica in a round-robin way.
   (Also working with several collections)
   That's actually not a bad way at all, as I can pass parameter when I launch an AMI/instance in AWS.

Thanks everyone.

Amir

Answer (score 0):

1) You are running the wrong command; the complete command is as follows:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=corename&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=10'
```

Here I have given replication factor and  due to which it will create the replica for your shards.

Comment: That's correct during setup time, not when you want to add replicas dynamically or during auto-recovery (without using addreplica command)

Comment: Hi Amir, 
Did my comment helped you in resolving your issue?
If not then can you please let us know what is the exact issue that you are facing?